# Error bars through simulation

Tags: variance, covariance, uncertainty

Supose I have made an experiment and got three sets of measurements :
$$X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$$
$$Y=\{y_1,...,y_n\}$$
$$Z=\{z_1,...,z_n\}$$

I also have three sets of standard errors for each measurement:
$$X=\{\Delta x_1,...,\Delta x_n\}$$
$$Y=\{\Delta y_1,...,\Delta y_n\}$$
$$Z=\{\Delta z_1,...,\Delta z_n\}$$

**I am interested in finding the uncertainty on the partial covariance $pcov$, where**
$$pcov(X,Y;Z)=cov(X,Y)-\frac{cov(X,Z)cov(Y,Z)}{var(Z)}$$

Is it wrong **knowing that these variables are not independent** to compute this partial covariance quantity for several **algorithmically generated** samples:
$$\{X_1',Y_1',Z_1'\}...\{X_N',Y_N',Z_N'\}$$

where each element of set $X_i'$ (resp. $Y_i'$, $Z_i'$) is chosen according to the probability distribution $\mathcal{N}(x_p,\Delta_{x_p})$ (resp...) found before, and then choose for the uncertainty on $pcov$ the variance of these algorithmically computed partial covariances, that is:
$$uncertainty\  on\ pcov(X,Y,Z)=var(\{pcov(X_1',Y_1',Z_1'),...,\{pcov(X_N',Y_N',Z_N')\})$$

Thank you all

Comment: I would have thought your simulation was a reasonable approach, though your notation is slightly confusing: presumably $Z_N'$ is the $N$th simulation of $Z'=\{Z_1',\ldots,Z_n'\}$ rather than being the $N$th element of $Z'$

Comment: Yes, right, I got confused, I modfied my post @Henry, so you think it's okay even though they're dependent ?